# processing eclipselink JPA results in async method in spring

Tags: spring, jpa, asynchronous, eclipselink

I need to process the JPA results in parallel , i am using multiple/nested async spring  method. below is the hierarchy.

TestScript
⇒ List of TestCases
        -> List of TestResults

Need steps like below:

1. select all the test script, list of testscripts
2. process all Test scripts same time using the async method [with specific thread pool]
3. process Testcases [list of test cases] in parallel using the async method with specified thread pool
4. wait complete all testcases step 3
5. wait to complete all the test scripts .

can we process result of one transaction [select] in multiple threads or how to handle this specific use case ☺,
⇒ I tried adding @transaction in each async method but no use
⇒ Do we need to inject DAO in async method class ?, [ I feel  it is unnecessary/overload  in my use case ☺)

I implemented the steps mentioned above, but getting exception

*Exception Description: A NullPointerException was thrown while extracting a value from the instance variable [id] in the object [null].*

please let me how we can handle above use case.

Comment: you mean all from a single EntityManager? and an EntityManager is not thread-safe

Comment: yes, how can we solve this?.   @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Scope("singleton")
    public synchronized AbstractPlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Named("entityManagerFactory") AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        return manager;
    }